# Can I book a seat for a suitcase?

Tags: tickets, luggage, seating, easyjet

Travelling on easyJet and the seat tickets are cheaper than the cost of putting a bag in the hold.

Can I book a seat and put the suitcase on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, **NO**.  Because EasyJet does not describe this as a possibility anywhere publicly. Also, since it would be difficult to secure a standard suitcase, the crew should object.

However, **YES**, if the 'suitcase' is actually a cello.  This is specifically described in EasyJet's baggage terms: [Musical Instruments](http://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/music-instruments)

Comment: "If You are making a Booking online at easyJet.com and wish to purchase a seat for a cello please add an additional seat during the online booking process and use the passenger name MR SEAT CELLO" :)

Comment: Thank you - now set me off googling cello cases.  Too late for this trip but something that could come in useful in the future.  I am hoping that that the case doesn't have to contain a cello.

Comment: @guest "woops, I accidentally mistook my clothes for my cello. Simple mistake, happens all the time."

Comment: @Belle Reminds me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Mistook_His_Wife_for_a_Hat  So there is precedence :D